# Largest momentum a man can generate with his body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, everyday-life, projectile, estimation

With just the human body and no extra help (e.g. no gunpowder), what is the maximum momentum one can impart to an object?

As an example, the fastest a human has thrown a baseball (weighing 0.145 kg) is 105 mph, yielding a momentum of about 6.8 kg*m/s. Can humans achieve higher than this? Perhaps by using a heavier object (like during a shot put or javelin toss)? Remember, I'm not asking for the largest speed generated, only the largest momentum generated. And using external tools (like gunpowder to fire a bullet) isn't allowed. Lastly, I'd like the answer to apply to a human imparting momentum to an extraneous object. But if the true answer is something like the High Jump (where one is imparting momentum to themselves/the earth), then I'll accept that too.

P.S.: No need for a super definitive specific answer. Just a rough idea that's on the order of what's optimal.

Comment: Gunpowder isn't a tool, it's an energy source. Then, there are "tools" like an archer's bow that store the user's own energy for later release. But, did you also mean to rule out simple implements like slings and [spear throwers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower)?

Answer (score 3):

$p =mv$, so you want big $m$ and big $v$. You want to avoid friction. So put something heavy on ice or an air hockey table or something.

Think of pushing a car. It would go faster and faster until it was going as fast as you can run.

Think of pushing a truck. It weighs more so it would accelerate more slowly.  But if you have done a good job of eliminating friction, it would accelerate. Eventually it would move as fast as you can run.

If you eliminate friction,  there is no limit to how big the object can be. So there is no limit to how much momentum you can impart.

Comment: +1. In vehicle pull events in strongman competitions, competitors impart huge amounts of momentum to heavy vehicles by pulling them for long periods of time.

Comment: My personal best is for a related quantity, angular momentum. There are fountains with a spherical concave base holding a spherical boulder.  A jet of water lifts the boulder a millimeter or so. The force isn't quite symmetrical,  so the boulder spins. You can reach in and slow the boulder to a stop. Then you can spin it up in a new direction.